# What is the smallest number of weighings needed to be able to identify the two heaviest nuggets from 16 nuggets?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

Any weighing gives 2 variants. So two weighing can give 4 variants, 3 weighing can give 8 variants and 4 weighing can give 16 variants.
If the common numbers of nuggets is 4 for two heaviest nuggets exist $A_{4}^2=12$ variants. So three weighing not enought but four weighing absolutly enought.
[Tournir method](http://datagenetics.com/blog/february42016/index.html) described this gives the answer.
But what about 16 nuggets? There are $A_{16}^2=16\cdot 15=240$ variants and 18 weighing which give $2^{18}$ much more numbers then needed teoreticaly. 
Teoreticaly should be enought 8 weighings IMHO because $2^8>240$. Is it true? Does exist better method for solving this problem (less then 18  weighings)?

**Remark.** From the problem  we should find two heaviest nuggets (without it's sorting) it's mean that exist not 240 but 120 different variants for 2 heaviest nuggets.

Comment: The page you link to has an excellent discussion.  No, you can't do it in less than $18$.  What is your problem with what it suggests?

Comment: even if I can put several nuggets into each scales?

Comment: No.  The counterfeit coin problems rely on the fact that most of the coins have the same weight.  A simple proof here is that the nuggets might have weights $2^n$.  Then each weighing just depends on the heaviest nugget on each side.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks I understand you. but if difference between each two nuggets is less than two times, could we decrease number of weighings (this suggestion is natural for this task)

Comment: No, in fact I think it makes it worse but is not so easy to demonstrate.  Suppose you have nuggets with weights 1.234, 2.315, 1.769, etc.  If you put more than one on the scale you don't know where you are.

Comment: but if I have some inequalities  for example $a+b+c>d+e+f; a+b+e<d+c+f; a+f>d+e; a<d$, maybe i can choose two heaviest stones